# Dynamic variables in Django base.html

Tags: django, authentication, orm

I have an app that uses flatpages and other constructs that don't take a `request` object. This causes problems in base.html. Here's a simple example.

If I wanted something like "Welcome {{ request.user.username }}!" at the top of every page, what's the best way to make that happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flatpages use `RequestContext` in [rendering templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/#how-it-works). Here's a bit more about [RequestContext](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1). Suffice to say, you should be able to write a Context Processor to add request.user to the context of every template. Something like this:

```
def user(request):
    """A context processor that adds the user to template context"""
    return {
        'user': request.user
    }
```

Which you would then add to your existing `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'context_processors.user',
)
```

You just need to make sure all your views bind `RequestContext` to their templates as well:

```
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
    my_data_dictionary,
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here's a good [read](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/) on Context Processors. They're a very helpful feature.

Comment: You don't need to write a context processor to add `user`, there's one built in and included by default: `django.core.context_processors.auth`

Comment: That was a really helpful link

Answer (score 2):

[Context processors](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1).