# How to use Dynamic variables in Django base.html

Tags: python, django

I want to output 'hello,XXX'(XXX=request.session['user']) at the top every page,so i write under code in base.html

```
hello {{ request.session['user'] }}
```

and there have TemplateSyntaxError:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '['user']' from 'request.session['user']'
```

there have a similar question but i really don't understand.
[Dynamic variables in Django base.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738837/dynamic-variables-in-django-base-html)

if XXX is a function return value,where to write this function and how to render this value?

thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with being in base.html. Neither does it have anything to do with functions, as you are not calling a function. The issue is simply that you have not read the documentation on template syntax. In a template, both attribute access and dictionary lookup are done with ".".

```
{{ request.session.user }}
```

Although I don't know why you want to use the session for this anyway, since the user is in request.user.

Comment: my app is a simple website and not use django auth. the SESSION['user'] will be created when user login ,request.session['user']={'uid':uid,'nickname':nickname},and there have hello XXX on the top of every page. and i write {{ request.session.user.nickname }} in base.html,it does't work but the session really created

Answer (score 2):

In Django you dont use list indexes in template code (like request.session['user']), instead you type it as a "sort of" function like: `request.session.user` to get it. This is just how the template system works.

In your use-case it might be worth noting that Django has an alias for `request.session.user` that is merely called `user`. So if you e.g. wanted to get the username you would do: `user.username` or `user.first_name` for their first name. You can of course achieve the same with `request.session.user.username`

Comment: if XXX is a function return value,how to render the value to base.html :)

Answer (score 1):

as far as i remember, there already is a `{{ user }}` available in Django templates, if you use the Django user auth system, so you could try to use `{{ user.username }}`.

You may also look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41547/always-including-the-user-in-the-django-template-context). Hope this helps.